# ubuntu cloud openstack on a single node - advantages and disadvantages

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, ubuntu-12.04, openstack, ubuntu-14.04

I would like to setup Ubuntu Cloud 14.04 on a single node. This could be extended to add new nodes in the future. Hence, thinking of setting the cloud.

What are advantages and disadvantages of this approach? Will it be a overkill at this point for a base setup on a single node?

Thanks!

Comment: try DevStack installation for OpenStack

Google it and you will find much information

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called Ubuntu Openstack installer that will deploy an entire Openstack cloud utilizing Juju, Openstack Icehouse, and optionally MAAS.

The project page with PPA's for Ubuntu 14.04 are available here: https://launchpad.net/~cloud-installer

Current documentation is available here: http://ubuntu-cloud-installer.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Please report any bugs you find during your experience so that we can quickly get those addressed for our next release.